# Echo message on startup without prompting

Tags: vimrc, echo

I'd like to echo a custom message upon startup, based on whether or not certain startup functions were successful. I tried this in my `.vimrc`

```
echo 'test'

"All my settings
...
```

I'd like vim to echo a message as if I had just typed

```
echo 'foo'
```

from the command line *after* opening vim, but instead I get this obnoxious dialog box that comes up before my vim windows has even opened. I also tried

```
exe 'echo "test"'
```

and

```
silent echo 'test'
```

but neither of these worked.

Comment: you might need to postpone the echo until VimEnter has fired

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to use an autocommand that runs after VimEnter is triggered.

The autocommand can look something like this:

```
autocmd VimEnter * echo 'foo'
```

When vim starts up, it runs the command, and 'foo' is visible in the bottom left, as it would if you had just run the command.

You would put this autocommand somewhere in your .vimrc

Comment: how do we can use this logic (autocmd VimEnter * echo 'foo') for vi editor. we can still view the file without echo message in "vi".

Comment: Something weird.. It's dumping partialy string conents to actual file contents on opening a new file. I think the `o` is interpreted as open line in insert mode.